# Visual Studio 2010: Create a Separate App_global.asax.dll while building/publishing a Web Application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

In a web application project in Visual Studio, when you Publish/Build, it produces a single assembly. I would like to have a separate app_global.asax.dll in addition to the application's compiled assembly. Is this possible?

Comment: Can I ask why you'd want to do that?

Comment: Just for learning reasons..